# Issue in javamail with multithreading

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Using javamail i am reading all the messages from inbox folder and use to pass the message object to executor one by one,. Executor use to read email body using get content  and use to categorize it and after categorizing it I use to move it to specific folder and use to delete it from inbox folder.

But in this process I am facing issue In get content method, it is returning me body of different mail. Seems like state sharing issue in multithreading environment in Java API. 
Can someone suggest me what can be the possible issue.

Comment: Is this an assignment for some class?  This is the second question like this in two days.  Note that all the threads are going to serialize on access to the connection so you'll get limited benefit from using an Executor.

Comment: As for your specific problem...  Are you closing the folder why the Executor is still accessing the Message objects?  If not, I need to see details of how you're passing the Message objects to the Executor.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Shannon, this is not assignment problem. I am closing the folder after processing of all the msgs. picked at that time.So it's like scheduler is running after a certain interval and it use to process all the msg available in inbox folder in that run. To make it faster, I am passing each msg object to executor and then in runnable class I am reading the content and classifying it and after classifying  I am deleting the msg in runnable class itself. Finally after completion of processing of all the msg, I am closing connection. Am I doing something wrong

Comment: If you do a lot of processing on each message, this is fine.  But if you do minimal processing on each message, then you're not going to get any benefit by using multiple threads since most of the time will be spent reading the message data from the server, which is serialized on the connection.  Ignoring that issue, as for why your application is failing, I still need to see more details to figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: Yes, there is lots of processing , that's the reason for multithreading. Also this issue is happening rarely.We have seen some frequent issue when the inbox size is huge > 400. My concern is can there be issue with calling inbox.expunge for deleting the processed message in runnable class. As I have seen message.getContent() is cached , not sure just assuming if this can cause problem.My issue is that I am getting the content of some different message rather then the Passed message object in runnable class

Comment: I think I've said this three times now...  I can't help you without more details and probably looking at your code.  If you don't want to post your code here, send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.  Also, are you using the latest release - [JavaMail 1.5.6](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)?